# Отправка ByteArray

Tags: http, android, java, post

Кодирую строку через `GZIP`, получаю `ByteArray`. Можно ли отправить его через `HTTP POST`, не создавая при этом файла на файле или в карте памяти?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите на это: [How to upload binary data using POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055278/how-to-upload-binary-data-using-post).